# Bug or hack? $GLOBALS

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

```
$GLOBALS["items"] = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ,'six', 'seven');
$alter = &$GLOBALS["items"]; // Comment this line
foreach($GLOBALS["items"] as $item) {
  echo get_item_id();
}

function get_item_id(){
  var_dump(key($GLOBALS["items"]));
}
```

Check output of this code, with commented and uncommented second line.
My result(PHP 5.3.0).
With second line

```
int(1) int(2) int(3) int(4) int(5) int(6) NULL
```

Without second line:

```
int(1) int(1) int(1) int(1) int(1) int(1) int(1)
```

Why so strange result?

Comment: I'm honest.. I have no idea.. getting the pointer of $GLOBALS shouldn't change the variable.

Comment: Nice hack. Apparently $alter takes over control. If you set $alter to NULL after assigning the array, the array becomes invalid even, and causes an error in the following loop.

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that `$GLOBALS` really is an array of references itself. And references in PHP are always funky.

Comment: @BoltClock, you can replace $GLOBALS to another array variable, and this hack works too)))

Comment: I fail to see why this should be a "hack". What is the advantage? Imo it is either a bug, weird behaviour or can be explained.

Comment: Not the same, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509979/unexpected-behaviour-with-php-array-references I don't see however, how getting a reference (without using it) should interfere.

Comment: @garvey - can u show your variant with another variable? http://pastebin.com/vkg6xkHk - my work correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a possible explanation:

We know that `foreach` always [loops over a copy of the array if it is not referenced](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Unless the array is [referenced](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), `foreach` operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. `foreach` has some side effects on the array pointer.

That means that the internal pointer of the original array is **not** changed and `key()` will always return the same value (as we can see when we comment out the line). And indeed if we do a `var_dump($GLOBALS)`, we get:

```
 ["items"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "three"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "four"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "five"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "six"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "seven"
  }
```

(no reference)

But as soon as we generate a reference to the array (with `$alter`), `$GLOBALS['items']` becomes a reference too, because both entries have to point to the same array:

```
 ["items"]=>
  &array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "three"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "four"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "five"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "six"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "seven"
  }
  ["alter"]=>
  &array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "three"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "four"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "five"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "six"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "seven"
  }
```

Hence, the `foreach` loop does iterate over the **original array** and changes the internal pointer, which affects `key()`.

---

To sum up: It is a problem with references, not with `$GLOBALS`.

Comment: +1 I'm imagine some poor guy who's trying to change values of this copied array in a foreach loop.